# How to disable user interaction with a parent layout when a child layout has been inflated in Android Programming?

Tags: android, parent-child, layout-inflater

I want to customize my alert dialogs in my application and not use alert dialog. What I have done was to create a layout that contains my popup warning with a dismiss button inside. When I inflate the popup warning xml layout from my activity, the popup shows, but the parent view can still be clicked on and interacted with. I have tried setting the parent layout a variety of ways when the popup layout is in focus. I have .setClickable(false); .setEnabled(false); setFocusable(false); setActivated(false). I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1):

1) use `DialogFragment`

2) use your custom view and inflate it in `onCreateView`

3) use below code inside the `onCreateView`

```
    getDialog().setCancelable(false);
    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Or just using a Dialog, if you aren't using Fragments.